# Generic-type operations must by provided by the run-time. Why this is a weakness of Go?

Tags: go

So, reading [golang blog on slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices) there is a snippet by Rob Pike

> A weakness of Go is that any generic-type operations must be provided by the run-time.

which I don't quite understand.

Can one rephrase same sentence?

Considering the context before and after this sentence I assume we can not program generic-type methods (consuming, let's say, slices of byte/int/float etc), but rather should use built-ins.

So, the quirkiest part for me is `provided by the run-time`, - is that equals to `provided by the language`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, the quirkiest part for me is "provided by the run-time," - is that equals to "provided by the language"?

Yes.  What it means is that Go has a handful of built-in generic types, such as arrays/slices, channels, and maps, that can have any type put into them, but that's all you get; there's no support for defining your own custom generic types.

Comment: However, one could use the `interface{}` (empty interface) type as the most general type.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's not a generic type, that's a `Top` type (supertype of all other types). "Generic types" usually means "parametric polymorphism", which is far more useful.

Comment: Yes, but I did not wrote: "generic type", so I knew that.